# Allowing images to display only when user is logged in.

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, session

I'm new to PHP/Web development and am trying to create a secured file viewer. 
I am using a form to login with PHP sessions, that checks a phpmyadmin database for valid info.

My question is how do I go about disabling direct path access, but allow the user to view the images when logged in?

I have tried .htaccess files. I have disabled the path, but can't figure out how to display the images with it.

Once I can display the images, does anyone have any suggestions on how I can make sure only people logged in can view them?

Thanks very much!

PS: First post! :) (can't seem to find enough info on other threads)

Comment: You probably mean MySQL or MariaDB instead of phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is a graphical tool for administrators to manage a database installation; the other two are actual database server software.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an PHP-script which checks if the user is logged in, and if so output the image (of what type of file it is). You can use [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) for that, there's an detailed examlpe on that page.

```
if ($userIsLoggedIn) {
    $path  = realpath($imagePath . '/' . $_GET['filename']);
    if (substr($path, 0, strlen($imagePath) + 1) == $imagePath) {
        // Check that the user doesn't request ../../../etc/shadow or something
        // Add headers
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        readfile($imagePath . '/' . $_GET['filename']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place files outside of normal access and access them via PHP like this:

```
header('Content-type: '.$type);  //$type = 'image/jpeg' but can be other file type
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path . $filename));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFileName.ext');
readfile($path . $filename);
exit();
```

Check if user can view this file and then show it as above. You can ditch Content-Disposition if you want show images.

But be sure you don't send other data before this.

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/forcedownload.html